# Evaluate integral: $\int\frac{C^2}{P^3-P^2C-QC^3} dC$, given $P,Q > 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I was trying to get a closed form solution of the integral

$$\int\frac{C^2}{P^3-P^2C-QC^3} dC$$
with $ P,Q > 0 $.

I went through the following steps:

$$\frac{C^2}{P^3-P^2C-QC^3} = \frac{-3QC^2}{-3Q(P^3-P^2C-QC^3)} \\+ \frac{-P^2}{-3Q(P^3-P^2C-QC^3)} + \frac{P^2}{-3Q(P^3-P^2C-QC^3)}$$

$$\int\frac{C^2}{P^3-P^2C-QC^3} \\= \int(\frac{-3QC^2-P^2}{-3Q(P^3-P^2C-QC^3)}+ \frac{P^2}{-3Q(P^3-P^2C-QC^3)}) dC$$

The first integral evaluates to:

$$\int(\frac{-3QC^2-P^2}{-3Q(P^3-P^2C-QC^3)}=\frac{-1}{3Q}\int(\frac{dz}{z}) =\frac{-1}{3Q}\log{z} $$

I am lost in evaluating the second integral :

$$\int\frac{P^2}{-3Q(P^3-P^2C-QC^3)} dC$$

Is there a closed form solution for this at all?

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming but in Mathematics has other meanings. Use `\cdot` ($\cdot$), `\times` ($\times$) or ideally simple juxtaposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite the integral as
$$I= -\frac1q \int\frac{x^2}{x^3 + \frac{p^2}q x-\frac{p^3}q}dx$$
and factorize  $x^3 + \frac{p^2}q x-\frac{p^3}q=(x-r)(x^2+rx+\frac{p^3}{qr})$,
with
$$r=\frac p{\sqrt[3]{2q}} \bigg( \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{1+\frac4{27q}}+1}-\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{1+\frac4{27q}}-1}\bigg)
$$
Then, integrate per partial fractions to obtain the close-form below
\begin{align}
I=& -\frac1q \int\frac{x^2}{(x-r)(x^2+rx+\frac{p^3}{qr})}dx\\
 =&\ -\frac1{p^3+2qr^3}
\int \frac{r^3}{x-r}+\frac{(p^3+qr^3)(2x+r)+ p^2r^2}{2q\ (x^2+rx+\frac{p^3}{qr})}\ dx\\
= &\ -\frac1{p^3+2qr^3}\bigg(
r^3\ln(x-r)+\frac{p^3+qr^3}{2q}\ln(x^2+rx+\frac{p^3}{qr})\\
&\hspace{35mm}+\frac{p r^2}q\sqrt{\frac{qr}{3p+r}}
\tan^{-1}\frac{p\sqrt{3p+r}\ (x+\frac r2)}{2\sqrt{qr}}
\bigg)
\end{align}

Comment: If I am nost mistaken $$r=\frac{2 P}{\sqrt{3Q} } \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3Q}  }{2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - Numerically, they are equivalent

Comment: @Quanto:  $(x-r)(x^2+rx+\frac{p^3}{qr})$ = $x^3+r^2x+\frac{p^3x}{qr}-rx^2-r^2x-p^3/q$ =$x^3+\frac{p^3x}{qr}-r^2x-\frac{p^3}{q}$. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: @Mechanician - Due to $qr^3+p^2r-p^3=0$
$$\frac{p^3x}{qr}-r^2x= \frac{(p^3-qr^3)x}{qr}=\frac{p^2x}q $$

Comment: Thank you @Quanto. May I also know how was the real root r determined ?

Comment: @Mechanician - The Cardano’s formula for the cubic equation

Comment: @Quanto : Would you mind explaining, how you arrived at the $ tan^-1$ term  from the last integral? The last integral is $\int\frac{p^2r^2}{2q(x^2+rx+\frac{p^3}{qr})}$, we can write $x^2+rx+\frac{p^3}{qr}$ as $(x+\frac{r}{2})^2-\frac{r^2}{4}+\frac{p^3}{qr}$ , then I am lost